# Executing Batch file in java gives unexpected results

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I have the following batch File : -

```
gcc temp.c -o temp.exe
pause
```

This batch file compiles a **.c** file. This batch script runs fine when executed by double clicking, but When I use java for that purpose, It gives me an error. The following is the code

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start CPrun.bat");
p.waitFor();
```

**CRun.bat**  is the name of the batch file.

The following is the error on cmd

```
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

**Note that gcc is my Compiler for C which is defined in the path of my Computer**

Comment: is gcc on path?

Comment: @pringi yeah, that's why it works fine on executing it directly

Comment: Try to give full path to gcc on CPrun.bat. I'm not sure how windows behaves with environment share between cmds

Comment: @pringi The full path gives the error. "C:Program...." is not recognized as a command. Am I typing the path incorrectly?

Comment: Are you using cygwin? Are you sure temp.exe is being generated when you run the script manually?

Comment: @pringi I am using MinGW which comes inbuilt with codeBlocks, and yes it does produce the .exe when run manually

Comment: @Shashwat when specifying the full path, did you surround it with double quotes : `"C:\Program..."`? Also you should be careful with calling batch scripts containing the `pause` command as it will wait on a key to be pressed. Be sure to handle all your output/input channels correctly?

Comment: Are you running the program from an IDE or directly from command line? If it is from an IDE then try first run from command line the program.

Comment: @J.Baoby Thanks, adding the quotes was the solution. Please write this as an answer. Also, can you explain why Environment Variables don't function in this batch ?

Comment: I've written an answer. I hope it can also help you with the environment variables. But what environment variables are you talking about??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the full path should do the trick. But **don't forget to surround it with double quotes `"`**. In batch it is recommended to surround all your paths with double quotes because in windows paths are very likely to contain whitespaces. Without the double quotes the whitespace will be handled as a delimiter, braking your paths in distinct parts (as if they were different arguments/executables).

About the environment variables: you will only have access to the environment variables your system passed to your JVM. To see these variables you can use `System.getenv()` it returns a string to string map, mapping environment variable names on their value. I have made [a little demo](http://ideone.com/FTkD6W) where all available environment variables are printed.